# How to set up Kubernetes (k8s) environment on an open-wrt based node connected in a cluster?

Tags: networking, cluster, kubernetes, openwrt

Openwrt OS support ".opk" file format extensions for the packages to be installed on the top of it.  For that k8s, kubelet binaries are availbale but the procedure is to generate an installable package in .opk format out of it. Is there any way to set up kuberentes (k8s) environment on it ? Does anybody know any specific way on how to set up k8s on openwrt based Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

K3s was made specifically for this - lightweight Kubernetes without the need for Docker dependency.
There is a makefile to generate OpenWRT packages here: https://github.com/discordianfish/k3s-openwrt

Or you can use K8s with docker as described in [this guide](https://5pi.de/2019/05/10/k8s-on-openwrt/).

Comment: Does k8s cluster connect with the nodes running k3s ?

Comment: Also we specifically desire to set up k8s on openwrt. The link which you suggested has makefile and binaries to generate k3s.

Comment: Have you tried to install [docker-on-openwrt](https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-on-openwrt) and then [building K8S normally](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build)? If it works you can then make a OpenWRT package by following the K3s example and changing it so that it builds K8s.